# How to automatically remove folder and files after deleting record with FileField attributes

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how which approach will be a more suitable way of storing files for the model described below:

```py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return f"books/{instance.slug}/{filename}"


class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100, verbose_name="URL")
    cover = models.FileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Cover"
    )
    epub = models.FileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="EPUB"
    )
    pdf = models.FileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="PDF"
    )
```

The folder structure of this approach looks like this:

```
mediafiles/
    books/
        <instanse.slug>/
            <cover>
            <epub>
            <pdf>
```

And the only problem I have here is that when I delete the entity of a book in the database, the <instanse.slug> folder is still there. I don't know what other issues could be here if there are any. So I'd like to know what could be a more practical solution for this particular model.

Comment: Its not because of folder structure. Django does not delete files upon deletion of the object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/1.3/#deleting-a-model-doesn-t-delete-associated-files

Comment: I use django-cleanup

Comment: django-cleanup does obviously  not know that the folder is only for that instance (seems not to be part of their logic) ... maybe modify django-cleanup to delete it if it is empty or whatever is your custom logic